# Video call between eyebeam and baresip SIP clients

Tags: video, sip, h.264, rtp, baresip

I am trying to achieve video call on 2 SIP clients

1. Baresip
2. Eyebeam

Till now I have succeeded in getting audio stream both ways but the video stream is one way i.e iam getting the stream at the baresip terminal but I cannot see video at the EYEBEAM terminal. I can't understand where I am going wrong.

The eyebeam is sending STAP-a and Fu-a packets to eyebeam as I checked it through wireshark. But baresip is not sending any STAP-a and Fu-a packets to eyebeam hence no video.. Both the clients support H.264.

Pointers in the right direction are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This question needs a log of at least one side to answer. Though, I guess one may check packetization mode.

- [Baresip only supports packetization mode=0](https://github.com/alfredh/baresip/blob/master/modules/gst_video/sdp.c#L43), AFAIK.
- ["FUA is used in packetization modes 1 & 2."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5307549/207791)
- "[a client shall support the use of STAP-A packets when packetization-mode 1 was negotiated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26393553/207791)."